# Deletion not happening in postgres on intel edison

Tags: postgresql, intel-edison

I am new to PostgreSQL DB and I tried installing it on the Intel Edison platform having ubilinux(Debian) OS.I succeeded in installing it.I could successfully create tables,insert rows etc using python module psycopg2.
But when I tried to delete the rows using psycopg2,the deletion does not happen.

Before I delete, the contents of the db are as follows:

(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

This is the code that I used to delete row number 4.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import psycopg2
import sys

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydb", user="root", password="edison")
print "Opened database successfully"

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DELETE FROM data WHERE S=4;")
conn.commit
print "Total number of rows deleted :", cur.rowcount

cur.execute("SELECT * from Data")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print row

print "Operation done successfully";
conn.close()
```

The output of this code is :

Opened database successfully

Total number of rows deleted : 1

(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

Operation done successfully

But when I now separately read the data in the database using "SELECT * FROM data;" , the contents in the database are:

(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

(8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

The row 4 is still present in the DB.This means the deletion has not happened at all.But when I now separately delete the row 4 in the database i.e without using python,using "DELETE FROM data WHERE S=4;",it works.But my requirement is deletion using python.

Can somebody help me?Thanks in advance.:)

Regards,
Arun

Comment: In almost all cases where I have seen things like this, the connection from within the program was done to a different database than the connection from the command line.

Comment: So is there a way out of this?

Comment: Did the first session COMMIT the data before the second one does the SELECT?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, there was an error in Line 12,
conn.commit()
I had missed the brackets.